# Can't access Live User Session account in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, live-usb

I made a new account with account type administrator. Somehow my live session user account is not listed in  User Accounts at System Settings. How to login as live session user again?

Answer (score 0):

The guest user account is not listed in the User Accounts screen in System Settings (at least in 12.04). If you want to log in as a live user you can do it in the login screen when you log out from the administrator user or when you switch on your computer and you go to the same login screen (if you don't have the automatic login for the administrator user).